# Redirecting user to url with username wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, redirect

I want to redirect users after login based on username.

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'wppbc_custom_login_redirect', 99, 3 );
function wppbc_custom_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $requested_redirect_to, 
$user ) {
   if( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
      return $redirect_to;
   }
   $username = $user->user_login;
   if ( is_array( $form_args ) ) {
      switch ( $username ) {
     case 'User1':
        $redirect_to = 'https://www.example.com/User1';
        break;
     case 'User2':
        $redirect_to = 'https://www.example.com/User2';
        break;
     default:
        $redirect_to = 'https://www.example.com';
      }
   }
   return $redirect_to;
}
```

The only problem is that no i have to manually add every user to this list with the domain i want them to be redirected to after a succesfull login. I want a single code where i can add the Username variable to the domain.

User name x logs in succesfully and will be redirected to www.example.com/x
User name y logs in succesfully and will be redirected to www.example.com/y

Can anyone help me with this code?

Comment: `$redirect_to = 'https://www.example.com/' . $username;`
just concat username at end of url

Answer (score 0):

You can not do like this
have to post back the javascript variable to your server before the server can handle the value. To do this you can either program a javascript function that submits a form - or you can use ajax / jquery. jQuery.post

Maybe the most easiest approach for you is something like this

```
function myJavascriptFunction() { 
  var javascriptVariable = "John";
  window.location.href = "myphpfile.php?name=" + javascriptVariable; 
}
```

On your myphpfile.php you can use $_GET['name'] after your javascript was executed.